Hollow Conical Shell Z-pinch Lithium Penning Gas For $^6Li$ + $^2H$ => $^4He2$ Fusion?
It occurred to me that boiling $^6Li$ as the thermal step in a Z-pinch device, given lithium's low first-ionization energy, might be a better way of creating homogeneous ions for the subsequent imposition of electric potential, as a step toward $^6Li$ + $^2H$ => $^4He2$ fusion.
So I imagined a conical cathode and flat anode wherein the introduction of potential is at the outer rims, propagating inward.

The idea being that a cylinder of plasma around the fuel gas corresponds to the exponential growth of conductive free electrons which progresses inward toward the fuel gas that has not yet been ionized by either the shockwave or the the exponentiation of free electrons at that radius.
As I understand conductive plasmas, the longer they are subject to currents, the more likely they are to evolve instabilities.  Moreover, the fuel gas at the center retains homogeneity until the last instant, at which point the inward momentum has accumulated.
There are undoubtedly many problems associated with this, but there is at least one very early study that appears to have involved a pinch geometry of this kind for the purpose of producing an ion beam.
Has this geometry been pursued in any of the varieties of Z-pinch fusion proposals?

Preheating of z-pinch loads has a long history, so yes one can preheat. But Li6-D fusion has a variety of other issues, particularly including D-D generating neutrons that then react with the Li6 to make T+He4, and now you have D-T reactions.
